# Ошибка InvocationTargetException при вызове модального окна

Tags: javafx, окно

```
public void showCreateProjectDialog(final ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    try {
        final String fxmlPath = "/fxml/creating.fxml";
        final String title = "Create new project";
        Stage createWindowStage = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
        createWindowStage.setTitle(title);
        createWindowStage.setResizable(false);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        createWindowStage.setScene(scene);
        createWindowStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        createWindowStage.initOwner(((Node) actionEvent.getSource())
                .getScene().getWindow());
        createWindowStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Участок кода где находится ошибка, нашел:

```
createWindowStage.initOwner(((Node) actionEvent.getSource())
                .getScene().getWindow());
```

Я не могу установить причину ошибки.
Единственное что я могу предположить, во всем виноват

```
fx:controller
```

который прописан в fxml.
Какие варианты еще могут быть?

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил, всего-то нужно было заменить

```
createWindowStage.initOwner(((Node) actionEvent.getSource())
            .getScene().getWindow());
```

на

```
 createWindowStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
 createWindowStage.showAndWait();
```